# Downloading documents Selenium and Firefox

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox, download

I just programmed the following code for downloading a document to a specific folder, however it keeps downloading in the default folder Downloads, what is the problem??
THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR HELPING

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import os

options = Options();
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Desktop/test-download");
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2);
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms- 
powerpoint");
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options);

driver.get("https://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/lwnyc2002/intro22.ppt") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("**xpath of document**").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `FirefoxProfile` for this action (indentation may be broken):

```
fprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fprofile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/Desktop/test-download")
fprofile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fprofile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fprofile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms- 
powerpoint")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```